# Python: how to drop rows in Pandas if two columns don't appear in another pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes `df` and `df1`. `df` contains name and attributes of people.

```
df  Name       Age
0   Jack       33
1   Anna       25
2   Emilie     49
3   Frank      19
4   John       42
```

while `df1` contains the info of the number of contacts between two people. In `df1` we can have some people that don't appear in `df`.

```
df1    Name1    Name2   c
0      Frank    Paul    2
1      Julia    Anna    5
2      Frank    John    1
3      Emilie   Jack    3
4      Tom      Steven  2
5      Tom      Jack    5
```

I want to drop all the rows from `df1` in `Name1` or `Name2` don't appear in `df`.

```
df1    Name1    Name2   c
0      Frank    John    1
1      Emilie   Jack    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `isin` -

```
df1[df1[['Name1', 'Name2']].isin(df.Name).all(1)]

#    Name1 Name2  c
#2   Frank  John  1
#3  Emilie  Jack  3
```

Or:

```
df1[df1.Name1.isin(df.Name) & df1.Name2.isin(df.Name)]

#    Name1 Name2  c
#2   Frank  John  1
#3  Emilie  Jack  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also use [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```
df1[np.isin(df1.Name1, df.Name) &
    np.isin(df1.Name2, df.Name)]
```